# How do you get this pie top?

Tags: dessert, pie, crust, filling

So I made a pecan pie, which turned out delicious.
[image: Pecan Pie]
However I was not a fan of the top of the pie.

How would I go about getting a top like that? How is this done in general?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you layer the pecans in the bottom of the pie shell, and then pour the custard/syrup over it.  The pecans then float to the top, creating a two layer pie.  You do want large enough pieces to float to the top--whole is traditional just for looking pretty.

Note also that you want to avoid beating air into the custardy/syrupy filling, which will rise to the top and help create the dryer layer above and around the nuts.

See for example, [this recipe](http://dearmartini.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/perfect-pecan-pie/) from Dear Martini, with an embedded video showing the method.

Comment: What if it's not a custard or syrup but more like a thick sugary mixture?

Comment: Its an egg sugar syrup.... call it whatever you like.